# Convert string array to cell

Tags: matlab

I need to output a cell to an excel file.  Before this I need to convert a date column of integers to datestrings.  I know how to do this, but I am not able to put this new string array back into the cell -

```
mycell = { 'AIR' [780] [1] [734472] [0.01] ; ...
           'ABC' [780] [1] [734472] [0.02]}
```

I did this -->

```
dates = datestr(cell2mat(mycell(:,4))) ;
```

What I need as an answer is:

```
{'AIR' [780] [1] '14-Dec-2010' [0.01] ;
 'ABC' [780] [1] '23-Dec-2010' [0.03] ; }
```

so that I can now send it to an excel file using xlswrite.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mycell = { 'AIR' 780 1 734472 0.01] ; ...
           'ABC' 780 1 734472 0.02]}

mycell(:,4) = cellstr(datestr(cell2mat(mycell(:,4))))

mycell = 

    'AIR'    [780]    [1]    '30-Nov-2010'    [0.01]
    'ABC'    [780]    [1]    '30-Nov-2010'    [0.02]
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that avoids the conversions is to use the function [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html):

```
mycell(:,4) = cellfun(@datestr,mycell(:,4),'UniformOutput',false);
%# Or an alternative format...
mycell(:,4) = cellfun(@(d) {datestr(d)},mycell(:,4));
```

Both of the above give the following result for your sample cell array:

```
mycell = 

    'AIR'    [780]    [1]    '30-Nov-2010'    [0.0100]
    'ABC'    [780]    [1]    '30-Nov-2010'    [0.0200]
```